# Rectangle packing, fixed sizes

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, geometry, reference-request, packing

I have rectangles of a given size to fit into a larger rectangle of a fixed size, with a specified gap between the packed rectangles. I would like to write some code that optimises the number of rectangles of each given size that I can pack.

For example, say I have a large rectangle of $8' \times 4'\ \text{(}\approx 2438 \times 1219 \text{ mm)}$, I would like to know the optimal placement and orientation of, say $x\ \text{(}400 \times 450 \text{ mm)}$ rectangles , $y\ \text{(}300 \times 400 \text{ mm)}$ rectangles and $z\ \text{(}680 \times 390 \text{ mm)}$ rectangles.

This is for a real life application (cutting ply into smaller boards), so ideally I would like to optimise for least number of cuts as they charge for each cut).

$eg$

[image]

(code standard manual `Graphics` manual placement:

```
Module[{s1, s2, s3}, s1 = {400, 450}; s2 = {300, 400}; s3 = {680, 390}; 
Graphics[{ EdgeForm[{Nest[Lighter, Blue, 2], Thin}], Nest[Lighter, Blue, 2], 
Rectangle[{0, 0}, {#, #2}] & @@ {2438, 1219},
Nest[Lighter, Red, 2], 
Rectangle[{0, 0}, {s1[[1]], s1[[2]]}],
Rectangle[{0, s1[[2]] + 5}, {s1[[1]], 2 s1[[2]] + 5}],
Rectangle[{s1[[1]] + 5, 0}, {2 s1[[1]] + 5, s1[[2]]}],
Rectangle[{s1[[1]] + 5, s1[[2]] + 5}, {2 s1[[1]] + 5, 
 2 s1[[2]] + 5}],
Rectangle[{s2[[2]] + 5, 2 s1[[2]] + 10}, {5 + 2 s2[[2]], 
 2 s1[[2]] + 15 + s2[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{0, 2 s1[[2]] + 10}, {s2[[2]], 2 s1[[2]] + 15 + s2[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 10, 0}, {2 s1[[1]] + 10 + s3[[2]], s3[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + s3[[2]] + 15, 
 0}, {2 s1[[1]] + 15 + 2 s3[[2]], s3[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 2 s3[[2]] + 20, 
 0}, {2 s1[[1]] + 20 + 3 s3[[2]], s3[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 3 s3[[2]] + 25, 
 0}, {2 s1[[1]] + 25 + 4 s3[[2]], s3[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 10, s3[[1]] + 5}, {2 s1[[1]] + 10 + s3[[1]],
  s3[[2]] + s3[[1]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 15 + s3[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5}, {2 s1[[1]] + 15 + s3[[1]] + s2[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5 + s2[[2]]}], 
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 20 + s3[[1]] + s2[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5}, {2 s1[[1]] + 20 + s3[[1]] + 2 s2[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5 + s2[[2]]}],
Rectangle[{2 s1[[1]] + 25 + s3[[1]] + 2 s2[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5}, {2 s1[[1]] + 25 + s3[[1]] + 3 s2[[1]], 
 s3[[1]] + 5 + s2[[2]]}]   }]]
```

Have searched for rectangle packing algorithm, but can't find any with these constraints.

*Added*

Using @GeorgeVarnavides ' code below, (though the `Fitting` option presents problems as outlined in comments below his answer), the method will also present practical problems as highlighted here

[image]

```
images = ConstantImage[Nest[Lighter, Red, 2], #] & /@ 
 Join[ConstantArray[#, 5], ConstantArray[#2, 4], 
  ConstantArray[#3, 6]] & @@ {{400, 450}, {300, 400}, {680, 390}};
 Show[ImageCollage[images, Automatic, {2438, 1219}, 
 Method -> "ClosestPacking", Background -> Nest[Lighter, Blue, 2], ImagePadding -> 5], 
 Graphics[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2438, 1219}], EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], 
Disk[{1875, 435}, 200],
Opacity[1], Thick, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1219}} &[1980]], 
Line[{{0, #}, {2438, #}} &[490]]}], Axes -> True]
```

as the guys at the timber yard will cut along the dashed lines since they can't cut part way accurately on a table saw. So noting @Syed 's comment, either [strip-packing or bin-packing](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Eepa/surveyhtml.html) looks like the way to go. No idea how to implement this in MMA though.

Another issue is that the `"ClosestPacking"` method doesn't rotate automatically to optimise packing.

Having said that, @GeorgeVarnavides ' answer does give me a great starting point to then adjust manually (+1).

Comment: Nice question, but very hard.

Comment: @yarchik I did wonder, though the guys at the local timber yard do have a programme that does this. I just wanted to optimize myself so I can play around with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-rectangles-of-different-sizes-into-the-sm

Comment: Not relevant to the math solution you are seeking here, but there is a Woodworking SE (that I just discovered). Perhaps you can get distilled and heuristic advice there.

Comment: https://www.cutlistoptimizer.com/

Comment: The guys at the local timber yard may well have a program to do that, but no way it can find optimal packing such as shown on the first figure here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square . You seems to be interested in a practical pragmatic solution. This imposes additional constraints of minimizing the number of cuts. You may be better off with a commercial solution.

Comment: @yarchick I'm not interested in optimal packing per se, as first figure is going to be very difficult to cut on table saw! Just optimal packing with constrains as outlined above. [Cutting in strips](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Eepa/surveyhtml.html) allowing for 90 degree rotation only would be what I'm after really. Near optimal is fine.

Comment: @syed, yes, [that's exactly what I'm after!](https://www.cutlistoptimizer.com/) Would be interested in algorithm / how to code in MMA though. Guess that means decoding JS though.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not a serious answer, but we could use the built-in "ClosestPacking" method available in [`ImageCollage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCollage.html), which conveniently also has a padding option:

```
SeedRandom[0];
images=ConstantImage[RandomColor[],#]&/@RandomInteger[{30,60},{12,2}];
packing=ImageCollage[1->images,ImagePadding->2,Method->"ClosestPacking",Background->Black];
HighlightImage[packing,ImageCorners[packing]]
```

[image]

Comment: the `Fitting` option in `ImageCollage` resizes the rectangles. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Neither `"Fit"`, `"Fill"` or `"Stretch"` work

Comment: `images = ConstantImage[Nest[Lighter, Red, 2], #] & /@ 
     Join[ConstantArray[#, 5], ConstantArray[#2, 4], 
      ConstantArray[#3, 5]] & @@ {{400, 450}, {300, 400}, {680, 390}};
Show[ImageCollage[images, "Fit", {2438, 1219}, 
  Method -> "ClosestPacking", Background -> Nest[Lighter, Blue, 2], 
  ImagePadding -> 5], Axes -> True]`

Comment: For example, if I change above to `ConstantArray[#3, 50]`, it resiozes the rectangles to fit, rather than keep original dimensions

Comment: Of course I can manually check, but was aiming at not doing that

Comment: You can specify all the weights as 1 to avoiding resizing, e.g. `Show[ImageCollage[1 -> images, ...]` but I don't think the `size` specification does what you want it to? I believe it's simply resizing the image post-collage

Comment: I did try that, but if I cange one of the dimensions to `ConstantArray[#3, 50]` it still manages to fit them all in! Whether I use `"Fit"`, `"Fill"`, `"Stretch"` or `"Automatic"` (it doesn't support `None`).